# Unable to summarize results without inflated values or duplicated detail rows

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm attempting to summarize data in a Report Header but keep running into incorrect summation or duplicated Detail rows.

There are two SQL views that I'm pulling data from, and can be simplified as the following:

**View_Invoice_Header:**

```
Invoice ID        Department        Total Amount
================================================
101               A                 30
102               B                 20
103               C                 5
104               C                 5
```

**View_Invoice_Detail:**

```
Invoice ID        Line        Department        Total Amount
============================================================
101               1           A                 30
101               2           A                 30
102               1           B                 20
103               1           C                 5
104               1           C                 5
104               2           C                 5
104               3           C                 5
```

In the report header, I want to display the totals for each **Department** like so:

```
Department        Total Amount
==============================
A                 30
B                 20
C                 10
```

I thought this would be easier to accomplish than it turns out.

1. If the tables are linked together (on **Invoice ID**), then Summarizing the totals from **View_Invoice_Header** by **Department** results in largely inflated values due to the **Total Amount** for each being multiplied by the number of linked Detail rows.
2. If the tables are not linked, Detail rows are duplicated by every Header row.

Are there ways around those problems or should I be attempting a different approach? The tables do not need to be linked, the Header view is only needed for summarizing the results in the Report Header.

Comment: You may need to look into using Running Total Fields instead of Summary Fields.  When you have duplicate details records a Running Total Field can allow you to omit the dupes from being summarized because you can set conditions on the evaluation and reset of the field.  For example, you can set it so that it only evaluates the value and rolls up into the summary when a field or group value you designate changes.

Comment: Don't Running Totals only work when inserted to the end of a report? When inserted to a report header, I'm only seeing the total from the first group.

Comment: Yes, Running Total Fields work best when placed in Footer sections.  When placed in a header, they won't accumulate totals correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new formula field like so:

`If {Line} = 1 Then {Total Amount} Else 0`

Summing this one up will give the required result. (Assumption here is that every invoice has exactly one line number 1.)

Comment: The only problem is when there are multiple invoices for a Department, doing MAX will only display the largest invoice in each Department.

Comment: You're right, I've overseen that. Will edit my answer accordingly...